# In AJD, when you run out of storage for non-JSON data, does the DB start rejecting new inserts of non-JSON type?

Tags: json, oracle-autonomous-db

We received notice that our production AJD database has exceeded the maximum allowed 20GB of Exadata storage for non-JSON data. We want to know if this will result in any production outage for us.

Do we have time to re-design our data elements so we can properly use the AJD database or do we need to urgently purge non-JSON data or convert to ATP?

We have not tried anything yet.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

We are not enforcing the limit programmatically at this point in time, so we won't bring your system to a grinding halt. You have time to redesign, nothing will break.

But you need to look into this, the check is there for a reason. You'd either have to reduce your relational data volume or consider upgrading to ATP. You can let me know offline if you have further questions, hermann.baer@oracle.com, stackoverflow is not the right place for that.